# Random on each row in a group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a below DataFrame:

I am trying to populate values in disbursedamount series as any random value between 10% to 20% of SanctionedAmount. This logic needs to be applied on each group of accountid.

```
Index  accountid  transdate  SanctionedAmount  balance  disbursedamount

0        103602 2018-08-01              7806     6798                0
1        103602 2018-11-01              7806     6798                0
2        103606 2018-11-01              6274     7313                0
3        103606 2018-06-01              6274     7313                0
4        103606 2018-07-01              6274     7313                0
5        103606 2018-08-01              6274     7313                0
6        103609 2018-11-01              5726     8189                0
7        103609 2018-07-01              5726     8189                0
8        103609 2018-08-01              5726     8189                0
9        103609 2018-06-01              5726     8189                0
10       103617 2018-07-01              6549     7457                0
11       103634 2018-06-01              8835     7794                0
12       103637 2018-07-01              6920     6623                0
13       103644 2018-06-01              8481     8253                0
14       103645 2018-11-01              8220     9966                0
15       103645 2018-06-01              8220     9966                0
16       103645 2018-07-01              8220     9966                0
17       103645 2018-08-01              8220     9966                0
```

Expected output:

```
Index accountid transdate  SanctionedAmount  balance disbursedamount

0   103602     2018-08-01     1000            798      100
1   103602     2018-11-01     1000            798      200
2   103606     2018-11-01     2000            313      200
3   103606     2018-06-01     2000            313      400
4   103606     2018-07-01     2000            313      200
5   103606     2018-08-01     2000            313      300
6   103609     2018-11-01     5000            189      500
7   103609     2018-07-01     5000            189      1000
8   103609     2018-08-01     5000            189      700
9   103609     2018-06-01     5000            189      800
10  103617     2018-07-01     3000            457      600
11  103634     2018-06-01     4000            794      700
```

Comment: `This logic needs to be applied on each group of accountid.` What does this mean?

Comment: Do you intend to apply this function group-wise or row-wise? They lead to two separate solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply multiply `SanctionedAmount` by a randomly selected number from a uniform distribution between 0.1 and 0.2.

```
df['disbursedamount'] = df['SanctionedAmount'] * np.random.uniform(0.10, 0.20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in locaccntrandom.index:
    locaccntrandom.loc[i,'disbursedamount']=((random.randint(10,15)* locaccntrandom.loc[i,'SanctionedAmount'])/100)
```

I used for loop for this and able to get the values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.apply()` with `np.random.randint()`:

```
df['disbursedamount'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0.1*x['SanctionedAmount'], 0.2*x['SanctionedAmount']), axis=1)
```

Using `np.random.seed(0)`, this gives:

```
       accountid   transdate  SanctionedAmount  balance  disbursedamount
Index                                                                   
0         103602  2018-08-01              7806     6798             1464
1         103602  2018-11-01              7806     6798             1339
2         103606  2018-11-01              6274     7313              819
3         103606  2018-06-01              6274     7313              986
4         103606  2018-07-01              6274     7313              636
5         103606  2018-08-01              6274     7313              904
6         103609  2018-11-01              5726     8189              642
7         103609  2018-07-01              5726     8189             1044
8         103609  2018-08-01              5726     8189              968
9         103609  2018-06-01              5726     8189              886
10        103617  2018-07-01              6549     7457             1140
11        103634  2018-06-01              8835     7794             1434
12        103637  2018-07-01              6920     6623              779
13        103644  2018-06-01              8481     8253             1022
14        103645  2018-11-01              8220     9966             1422
15        103645  2018-06-01              8220     9966             1499
16        103645  2018-07-01              8220     9966             1359
17        103645  2018-08-01              8220     9966              894
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to use random function
here is a simple option

```
   from random import random
   df.disbursedamount = df.SanctionedAmount * (random()/5)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your expected output, it looks that you do not require the logic "to be applied on each group of accountid", i.e. no need of functions such as `groupby`. So the solution to each row is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# df = the_DataFrame_you_have
df['disbursedamount'] = df['SanctionedAmount'] * np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.2)
```